# Error 500 When Accessing Yammer Through Proxy Server

Tags: proxy, 500-error, chrome

We have direct access enabled and web traffic is routed through a proxy server. Can someone help identify where I need to go with this issue where opening Yammer results in error 500.

When on the direct access network working remotely, Yammer is opened from the Office 365 portal in Chrome. It displays error 500 for the Nginx server with IP address 13.107.6.159. When I ran a whois lookup it looks like this is a Microsoft owned server.

It is true that emptying the cache in Chrome does sometimes work, but it always reverts back after a reboot.

I have been to the network tab in Chrome and it shows the following information:

```
Response Headers:

Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 572
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2021 09:05:20 GMT
nel: {"report_to":"default","max_age":3600,"success_fraction": 0.001}
report-to: {"max_age":3600,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://mmay.nelreports.net/api/report?cat=yammer-prod_central_1"}]}
strict-transport-security: max-age=1234513412313; includeSubDomain
Via: 1.1 hosted.websense 13lonb
X-Bst-Info: t=1611047121,h=13lonb,p=29191_51738:2_12031,u=757195352,c=25124,c=100199,v=7.11.74286.256
X-Bst-Request-Id: tvTDtj:KnZ:305750
x-lodbrok-cell: prod_central_1-c2
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 123DB7D71E3946A8B18FCA4BD1A85794 Ref B: LON21EDGE0513 Ref C: 2021-01-19T09:05:21Z
x-robots-tag: none

Request Headers:
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: www.yammer.com
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://www.office.com/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36
```

I will attach a screen shot as well.
[image]

I admit that I am not the best at troubleshooting network issues like this. Can someone please advise where I need to look to resolve this.

Comment: You need to look at the logs on the web server.

Comment: I think the web server belongs to Microsoft. I have logged a ticket with them.